# uitableviewcells, design concerns

Tags: ios, uitableview

I think I'm not lucid anymore...
I want to display data - retrieved from a server - in a UItableView. To do so I created

1. A wrapper class to store data elements collected from a server. All of them are then stored into an array.
2. A UITableViewCell subclass to display the data into a custom cell
3. A Xib file, associated to the UITableViewCell defined in point 2)

In cellForRowAtIndexPath: , I dequeue instances of 2+3) an associate the fields of 1) to their counter parts in defined in 2).

To me this looks like a lot of stuff.

But removing 1) seems difficult, as dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: manages it's own pool of objects, so it doesn't really make sense to create an array of UITableViewCells in step 1)

Removing 3) may be possible, but adds extra over-head when setting up the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath:

Anyone has found a way to trim-down on this class crowd ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your cell is not too complex, then you can create it by code in the controller you are displaying data.

If your cell has a higher complexity, then there isn't really a way to trim it down. Besides 2 classes + a resource file is not that much really for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: That's eventually what I suspected. Thanks !